# hardcoded marker are showing but not showing markers when i get data from json in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, maps

I am using google maps to display markers on google maps. When I enter the data that is hardcoded it shows the markers but when I pass the JSON data to the markers it does not show. I compare the two there is no difference both are a list of markers. Can Anyone guide me on what am I doing wrong?
Here is my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:CityKey/providers/businesses.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MapsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/maps-screen';

  @override
  _MapsScreenState createState() => _MapsScreenState();
}

class _MapsScreenState extends State<MapsScreen> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final businesses = Provider.of<Businesses>(context, listen: false);
    final jsonBusiness = json.encode(businesses.business.toList());
    List<Marker> list = [
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('Marker1'),
        position: LatLng(32.195476, 74.2023563),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Business 1'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
      ),
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('Marker2'),
        position: LatLng(32.162969, 74.193625),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Business 2'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
      ),
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('Marker3'),
        position: LatLng(32.139505, 74.209312),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Business 2'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
      ),
    ];
    print('List of markers $list');
    // setState(() {
    //   markers.addAll(list);
    // });
    // print('list of markers $markers');
    final List jsonList = json.decode(jsonBusiness);

    final List listofLatLong = jsonList
        .map(
          (e) => Map.fromEntries([
            MapEntry(
              'business_address_longitude',
              e['business_address_longitude'],
            ),
            MapEntry(
              'business_address_latitude',
              e['business_address_latitude'],
            ),
            MapEntry(
              'business_title',
              e['business_title'],
            ),
            MapEntry(
              'business_id',
              e['business_id'],
            ),
          ]),
        )
        .toList();

    final title = listofLatLong
        .map((e) => Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId('Marker${e['business_id']}'),
              position: LatLng(
                double.parse(e['business_address_latitude']),
                double.parse(e['business_address_latitude']),
              ),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: e['business_title'],
              ),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                  BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
            ))
        .toList();
    print('List of markers my $title');
    setState(() {
      markers.addAll(title);
    });
    // print(markers);
    // print('This is the business ');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Maps'),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(32.1749132, 74.1779387),
          zoom: 11.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any stacktrace or error logs? Also you should remove `setState`from here:
```setState(() {
      markers.addAll(title);
    });
```
Just use: `markers.addAll(title);`
There is no need for the setState inside a build method

Comment: Hey @yusufpats this occurred due to the provider package I am using to get the value I stored the value in the var which the provided is changing as it entered in the build context. All I do it stored in the final then pass the arguments to the map it resolve my issue. Thanks for helping and soory for late response. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurred due to the provider package I am using to get the value I stored the value in the var which the provided is changing as it entered in the build context. All I do is stored in the final then pass the arguments to the map it resolve my issue.